# Spring WebClient BodyInserters.fromResource() changes content-type?

Tags: java, spring, webclient, content-type

I'm new to Spring's WebClient.  I'm trying to post the contents of a file using the content-type application/octet-stream.  Initially I loaded the contents of the file into a byte array and used .bodyValue() to add it.  This works perfectly.

```
byte[] data;
 
// read file into byte array here ...

FileUploadResponse resp = client.post().uri(uri)
     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
     .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .bodyValue(data)  // From byte[]
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(FileUploadResponse.class)
     .block();
```

Obviously loading the entire contents of the file into memory is not great.  So I did a little searching and it looks like I need to use a "from resource body inserter."   So I changed the code to this:

```
// Use a Spring FileSystemResource that will be used to insert the data into the body.
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(localFilename);

// Create a web client
WebClient client = WebClient.create();

FileUploadResponse resp = client.post().uri(uri)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource)) // From file resource
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(FileUploadResponse.class)
        .block();
```

Now the content-type is being sent as "text/plain" (see below)

```
POST /fileupload
accept-encoding: gzip
user-agent: ReactorNetty/0.9.11.RELEASE
host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept: application/json
```

What am I doing wrong?  Does the BodyInserters.fromResource() always override the content-type to "text/plain"?  Is there some other way I should be doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of the [specific handling](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/b595dc1dfad9db534ca7b9e8f46bb9926b88ab5a/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/codec/ResourceHttpMessageWriter.java#L145) of the `application/octet-stream` in `ResourceHttpMessageWriter`. It tries to detect mime type by file extension.

You could use `InputStreamResource` instead to keep `application/octet-stream`

```
var resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(localFilename));
```

Comment: That's non-intuitive and not documented anywhere.  Phew!  I'm glad you happened to know Alex otherwise I'd be banging my head for a long time on that one.  I'll give the InputStreamResource a shot tomorrow and mark yours as the correct answer.   Thanks again!

Comment: I confirmed this morning your solution works as expected.  Thank you again Alex!  I appreciate it.